# jQuery - Show and hide button

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have written a script that shows a submit button when clicking inside an input area. And when clicking outside the input, the button should be hidden. There are several areas and buttons, therefore I have assigned a unique ID to every button and area.

The problem is: When I click the area, the button shows. But when clicking outside, nothing happens. The script works if I only have one button and area, but when assigning IDs, it stops working...

```
$(".textarea").click(function(e) {
    var cid = $(this).attr('rel');

    $("#submit" + cid).show();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function() {
    $("#submit" + cid).hide();
});
```

Comment: `document` object isn't clickable area

Comment: Is anything assigned to cid at the point of clicking the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".textarea").click(function(e) {
    var cid = $(this).attr('rel');

    $("#submit" + cid).show();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function() {
    //add logic to hide all submit buttons by assigning common class to all
});
```

Comment: please mark it as answer if you got the solution :)
Happy coding

Answer (score 4):

The variable `cid` is declared in the anonymous text area click handler.  So, when the other function is called as a result of a click, it does not have a value.

Change you hide function to something independent of `cid` like this

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $("button[id*=submit]").hide();
});
```

The `id*=submit` section will look for all buttons that have `submit` in the `id` and hide them.  This will circumvent the need to track `cid`.  If you have other buttons with `submit` in the id that you do not want to hide, then selecting based on a class or changing the id format will be required.